# How to implement callable distance metric in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, euclidean-distance, keyword-argument

I'm using the clustering module in python's scikit learn, and I'd like to use a Normalized Euclidean Distance.  There is no built-in distance for this (that i know of) Here's a [list](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances).

So, I want to implement my own Normalized Euclidean Distance using a callable.  The function is part of my `distance` module and is called `distance.normalized_euclidean_distance`.  It takes three inputs:  `X`,`Y`, and `SD`.

However, Normalized Euclidean Distance requires standard deviation for the population sample.  But, the pairwise distance in scipy only allows two inputs: `X` and `Y`.

How do I allow it to take an additional argument?

I tried putting it in as a `**kwarg`, but that didn't seem to work:

```
cluster = DBSCAN(eps=1.0, min_samples=1,metric = distance.normalized_euclidean, SD = stdv)
```

where `distance.normalized_euclidean` is the function that I wrote that takes in two arrays, `X` and `Y` and computes the normalized euclidean distance between them.

...but this throws an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'SD'
```

What is the way to use additional keyword arguments?

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) it says `Any further parameters are passed directly to the distance function.`, which made me think that this would be acceptable.

Comment: I thought about using a global variable for `stdv`, but this seems like a dangerous solution.

Comment: what is `distance.normalized_euclidean`?

Comment: it's the function that i wrote for computing NED.

Comment: Then how is `SD` used? Isn't it also an argument of `distance.normalized_euclidean`?

Comment: Yes, it is also an argument of `distance.normalized_euclidean`.

Comment: Your link to "here" is to ``pairwise_distances``, but you give it to the ``__init__`` of ``DBSCAN`` which has no ``**kwargs``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda function as metric which takes two input arrays:

```
cluster = DBSCAN(eps=1.0, min_samples=1,metric=lambda X, Y: distance.normalized_euclidean(X, Y, SD=stdv))
```

Comment: I think this is currently the only way to do it, as dbscan has no kwargs. I think it is a reasonable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by using the metric_param arg, which is later sent to the function as kwargs:

```
cluster = DBSCAN(eps=1.0, min_samples=1, metric=normalized_euclidean, metric_params={"SD": stdv})
```